# Pandas: create new dataframe column from series of arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of numpy arrays, and would like to create a dataframe column from it. Specifically, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [298]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A','A','B','B'], 'value': [1,2,3,4]})

In [299]: df
Out[299]: 
  name  value
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    B      3
3    B      4
```

I now calculate the cumulative integral per 'name' like this:

```
In [300]: g = df.groupby('name')

In [301]: r = g.apply(lambda x: np.insert(integrate.cumtrapz(x.value), 0, [0]))

In [302]: r
Out[302]: 
name
A    [0.0, 1.5]
B    [0.0, 3.5]
dtype: object
```

The type of r and elements of r are:

```
In [303]: type(r)
Out[303]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [304]: type(r[0])
Out[304]: numpy.ndarray
```

I would like to add this result to the original dataframe, achieving:

```
In [308]: df['cumint'] = np.append(r[0], r[1])

In [309]: df
Out[309]: 
  name  value  cumint
0    A      1     0.0
1    A      2     1.5
2    B      3     0.0
3    B      4     3.5
```

What is the best way of achieving this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` instead of `apply` here like to get the results as a series:

```
df['cumint']=(df.groupby('name')['value'].
          transform(lambda x: np.insert(integrate.cumtrapz(x), 0, [0])))
#or df['cumint']= g['value'].transform(lambda x: np.insert(integrate.cumtrapz(x), 0, [0]))
print(df)
```

---

```
  name  value  cumint
0    A      1     0.0
1    A      2     1.5
2    B      3     0.0
3    B      4     3.5
```

Comment: Even though nick's answer works perfectly, I think this is a simpler (one less step), and thus the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your series contains numpy arrays so you can [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) the elements of the series into one long numpy array and set the new column to this array:

```
df['cumint'] = np.concatenate(r, axis=0)
```

Result:

```
>> print(df)
  name  value  cumint
0    A      1     0.0
1    A      2     1.5
2    B      3     0.0
3    B      4     3.5
```

Comment: This works perfectly with my apply() approach, but anky's suggestion of using transform() instead removes this requirement.